# Timeout to open TCP connection to smtp.sendgrid.net:587 (exceeds 5 seconds) in Rails 7 when sending email in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, sendgrid

im trying to send email real time in development, but i have time out error using
sendgrid. My configuration is below

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

```
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
     :user_name => 'apikey', # This is the string literal 'apikey', NOT the ID of your API key
     :password => ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'], # This is the secret sendgrid API key which was issued during API key creation
     :domain => 'localhost:3000',
     :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
     :port => 587,
     :authentication => :plain,
     :enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timeout limits and check if it works.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  # ...
  open_timeout: 20,
  read_timeout: 20,
}
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration